# Does Complete execute Trigger for DataFlow blocks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I have two pipelines using multiple Buffer, Batch, and Action blocks from the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow namespace.  I understand once all work items have been added to the pipeline that the `Complete` method should be called.  However, if the Batch blocks are processing 250 items at a time, will calling the `Complete` method actual call the `Trigger` method internal to ensure any pending items are completed.

For example, if the Batch blocks are batching 250 items at a time, 251 items are given to the pipeline, and `Complete` is called, will the one remaining item be processed by the entire pipeline?  If not, I am assuming I will need to implement my own flag and logic to ensure all remaining items are passed through the pipeline as well as the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a [`BatchBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1) is marked as complete with the `Complete` method, it stops accepting any more messages, and emits a final batch containing any leftover messages that are currently in its input queue. Obviously the size of the last batch can be smaller that the specified `batchSize`. In short you don't have to do anything special. The `BatchBlock<T>` does the correct thing by itself.

When the last batch stored in the output queue of the `BatchBlock<T>` is accepted by a linked block downstream, the `BatchBlock<T>`'s `Completion` property transitions to the `RanToCompletion` state.

Comment: Great.  I knew it stopped accepting more messages, and I assumed it outputted the last batch, I just wanted to confirm that it would travel down the remaining pipeline blocks.  I appreciate the feedback.